# How do I get Sublime Text 2 to work with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, sublimetext2, homebrew

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I’ve installed XCode, Homebrew, RVM, Ruby and Rails.

Now how do I get Sublime Text 2 to work with Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should do is install [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) if you haven't already. This will make downloading packages and plugins way easier. Then you can look at some of the Rails specific packages to make your life easier when coding with Sublime Text.

Sublime Text has native support for syntax coloring in .rb files, so you don't have to install anything for that. Dragging your project folder and dropping it on Sublime Text will open it.

Keep in mind, though, that Sublime Text is simply a text-editor - not an IDE. You won't get a lot of help like code completion (although [there are plugins](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) that can help a bit) or complaining when your syntax is wrong (again, there might be a plugin for this). For that, look at something like Netbeans or IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2):

You can download and install Sublime Text if you haven't done yet from [sublimetext.com](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).

Here is [an installation guide for OS X Terminal](https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170) that I found cool.

You should install [Package Control for Sublime Text](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation).

Then I suggest you check out these videos:

- [Sublime Text 2 Tutorials #1 - Installing & Overview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k01udDD-UwI)
- [Perfect Workflow in Sublime Text 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ-bgcJ6fQo)

It's worth spending time with it once, and it will save a lot of time in the future.