# What considerations/solutions should be taken into account for setting up Sublime 2 for rails and ruby coding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ide, sublimetext2

I have tried BBedit and RubyMine for building Rails apps and I would like to try out Sublime 2.  What add ons should I include?

Comment: What ones are you considering?  I am afraid this question will likely be voted to be closed as "closed as not constructive."  You may want to read the [what kind of questions to avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) article.

Comment: Thanks to twitter responses which pointed me at -> [How do I get Sublime Text 2 to work with Ruby on Rails?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900131/how-do-i-get-sublime-text-2-to-work-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so this is what I found in different places

1. Establish that you access sublime from the command line

This is the actual set of answers that worked for me, note the version of Mac OSX and the version of Sublime [Open Sublime Text from Terminal in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199581/sublime-text-3-subl-command)

2. Install the Package Controller
   https://sublime.wbond.net/installation
3. Install the Soda theme from package controller
4. Install the following packages -> SCSS, ApplySyntax, Git and RSpec